# Saving Gtalk chat history after "Go off the record" enabled

Tags: google-talk

I have a Google Apps Business account. The users in the organization use Gtalk to chat. It is compulsory to save chat history but the users change the settings and "go off the record".

Is there any way to record the chats even if users have clicked "Go off the record"?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "Going off the record" is to not include the chat into your history...

Doing what you request would just be "Going back on the record".